# Как сделать, чтобы все vue приложение загружалось только после получения данных с сервера?

Tags: vue.js, vuex, nuxt.js

Пишу приложение на vue/nuxt и назрела такая проблема. Я получаю с сервера токен для авторизации и обновляю его каждый раз при запуске приложения. Все запросы в дальнейшем строятся при помощи этого токена. Токен получал в дефолтном layout при dyenhb created()
Частично проблема решалась при помощи BusEvent, но возникла необходимость проверять, а имеет ли пользователь право просматривать открытую страницу. Хочется сделать через middleware, но он срабатывает, получается, раньше, чем получение токенов и сервер выдаст 401.
А писать на каждой странице запрос внутри created() мне кажется нерациональным.
Как можно вписать полученный с сервера токен в vuex, чтобы потом из любого места его брать?

Comment: У меня пожалуй нет ответа на вопрос, но есть иной вариант решения. Пускай имеется какой-нибудь глобальный миксин или лучше Vuex-хранилище. В хранилище организуйте процесс получения токена и его возврата. Поскольку приложение загружается раньше, чем приходит токен, возврат токена отдаёт Promise с ним. Если в данный момент идёт загрузка - Promise запроса, а если нет, то просто оберните токен в промис.

Comment: Дальше везде, где нужен токен, используйте этот метод. И конечно же не забывайте писать await. Таким образом страница всё-равно откроется быстрее, чем придёт токен, но весь код, который с ним работает, будет ждать его загрузки. Да и более того, токен загружается только один раз и живёт в хранилище пока страница не закрыта.